# html5sql.js: How to chain sql statements using prior results?

Tags: javascript, sql

My first time posting on this forum!

I've been utilizing the `Html5sql.js` module in one of my Phonegap apps.

It's been very useful thus far, but I've been having some difficulties in that I need to use the results of one of queries from one of the sql objects in the following sql object.

The documentation states that if the success callback function returns an array, then it will be used as the data parameter for the next SQL statement to be processed.

This is what I have so far.

I've tried declaring the temp array on the outside of the process and have also tried to plug in "data": temp within the secondary sql object.

I've also attempted to remove the data parameter entirely from the 2nd object, but have had no success.

```
    html5sql.process(
            [
                {
                    "sql": "SELECT MAX(sir.id) as uid FROM stepsInRoutine sir WHERE sir.routine_id = (?)",
                    "data": [routineId],
                    "success": function(transaction, results, rowsArray){
                        console.log('++++++++++++ ' + rowsArray[0].uid);
                        temp = new Array(); 
                        temp[0] = rowsArray[0].uid;
                        return temp;
                    }
                 },
                 {
                        "sql": "SELECT * FROM stepsInRoutine WHERE id = (?)",
                        "data": [temp[0]],
                        "success": function(transaction, results, rowsArray){
                            console.log('---------ROWSARRAY---------------' + rowsArray[0].stepId);
                        } 
                 }
             }
            ],
            function(){
                console.log('RSLAPO SUCCESS');
            },
            handleError
        );

}
```